# A natural number between two reals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

How should I go about proving the following:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$

$ s.t. $

$20(3x^2 - 3x + 2) > 15n > 12(5x^2 - 5x + 2)$

Comment: Just expand the parentheses and you'll see.

Comment: I tried expanding and made the same realization as @andrew-chin, but have no idea how to make this idea rigorous.

Comment: You get $A+40$ for the left side, and $A+24$ for the right side, with the same $A$. This open interval of length $16$ surely contains $15$ consecutive integers, and one of them must be divisible by $15$.

Comment: Consider $$ 4x^2-4x+\frac{40}{15}\gt n\gt4x^2-4x+\frac{24}{15} $$ and $\frac{40}{15}-\frac{24}{15}=\frac{16}{15}\gt1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $A=60x^2-60x+24$ and $B=15n.$ The inequality rewrites $$A+16>B>A.$$ Whatever is the real $A,$ the interval $(A,A+16)$ contains at least $15$ consecutive integers ($15$ if $A$ is an integer, $16$ otherwise).
One of them is a multiple of $15.$ It can be written as $15n$ for an integer $n.$

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what do you mean by "one of them is a multiple of 15"?

Comment: In a list of $n$ consecutive integers, at least one of them is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$$20(3x^2-3x+2)>15n>12(5x^2-5x+2)$$ expands into
$$60x^2-60x+40>15n>60x^2-60x+24$$

Simplifying, we get
$$0<15n-24+60x-60x^2<16$$

Loosely put, since there is a range of $16$ in $(0,16)$, by adding or subtracting a multiple of $15$, you will always be able to land $-24+60x-60x^2$ within $(0,16)$.  I'm not sure how rigorously you would like this to be proven, but here is a start, given that we haven't seen your thoughts or efforts.

Comment: I noticed this too, but how can I put this rigorously? Sorry, I should have mentioned this realization in the original post.